# Playing H264 video stream (from raspberri pi) in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, video-streaming, media-player

I have a working streaming device (raspberry pi with camera module - it has a tool called "raspivid"), from which I am streaming live video using netcat

```
raspivid -t 999999 -w 300 -h 300 -hf -fps 20 -o - | nc -l 9999
```

In Ubuntu, after connecting to the device using netcat and streaming video to mplayer, everything works like a charm...

```
nc *ip* 9999 | mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es -
```

Now, I want to make this video available for Windows users (with minimal setup required, possibly only an .exe).
I decided to use Qt 5 - it has qTcpSocket and QMediaPlayer (according to doc, it supports stream-input). 
I already have some code which can read data from socket and also play local files.

But playing streams does not seem to work. Maybe it is because the video format and some codecs ? WMP also cant play the video I saved using raspivid, although vlc plays it perfectly.
I also tested cat'ing a simple .avi file (which Qt plays successfully from local disc) in raspberry pi and playing the same TcpStream in Qt with no success.

Also, after netcat'ing from PI and running the compiled program in Windows, I can see that the LED on wifi dongle on raspberry pi starts flashing - so the stream arrives in the application.

Could you maybe give me some advice, what to do/try next?

I have not much previous experience with C++, so if I am asking something really wrong, please do not hit me too hard :)

Also, the "SimpleChatClient" comes from a random template I started working on..

```
SimpleChatClient::SimpleChatClient(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags)
: QWidget(parent, flags)
{
    QVBoxLayout* main   = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    player = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);
    QVideoWidget* widget = new QVideoWidget;
    widget->show();
    player->setVideoOutput(widget);
    main->addWidget(widget);
    setLayout(main);
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(playStream()));
    toggleConnection();
}

SimpleChatClient::~SimpleChatClient()
{
}

void SimpleChatClient::toggleConnection()
{
    if (socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
    {
        socket->connectToHost(SERVER, PORT);
    }
    else
    {
        socket->disconnectFromHost();
    }
}

void SimpleChatClient::playStream()
{
    player->setMedia(QMediaContent(), socket);
    //player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\Users\\m\\d.avi")); //This works for local files
    if (socket->canReadLine())
    {
        player->play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the fact that its a h264 stream you are catting to disk? AFAIK, WMP can only play container (such as mp4) files. So if you put your h264 stream into an mp4 you may have better results. Just a hunch though as I've done that before. VLC can playback raw h264 streams.

Comment: You can use `raspivid -t 0` to stream forever instead of `-t 999999`